# RecyclerView make item from selected to not selected when DialogFragment appears

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented ta `RecyclerViewAdapter` with `OnRecyclerItemClicked Listener` that way:

```
public class MyRecyclerViewButtonsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewButtonsAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private List<String> buttonNames;
    private OnRecyclerItemClicked onRecyclerItemClicked;
    private int selectedPosition;

    public MyRecyclerViewButtonsAdapter(String[] buttonNamesArr, int currentSelectedPosition, OnRecyclerItemClicked listener) {
        this.buttonNames = new ArrayList<>();
        this.selectedPosition = currentSelectedPosition;

        for (int i = 0; i < buttonNamesArr.length; i++) {
            buttonNames.add(i,buttonNamesArr[i]);
        }

        onRecyclerItemClicked = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.button_item, null);
        return new CustomViewHolder(view, onRecyclerItemClicked);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.button.setText(buttonNames.get(position));
        holder.button.setPressed(position == selectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != buttonNames ? buttonNames.size() : 0);
    }


    public int getSelectedPosition() {
        return selectedPosition;
    }

    public void setSelectedPosition(int selectedPosition) {
        this.selectedPosition = selectedPosition;
    }

    class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        protected Button button;
        protected OnRecyclerItemClicked itemClickedListener;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view, OnRecyclerItemClicked itemClickedListener) {
            super(view);
            this.button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_item);
            this.itemClickedListener = itemClickedListener;
            this.button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            itemClickedListener.onRecyclerItemClicked(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public interface OnRecyclerItemClicked {
        void onRecyclerItemClicked(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

I use state xml file to simulate that button is pressed as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_main_btn_prs" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_main_btn_prs" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_main_btn_prs" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_main_btn" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_main_btn"/>

</selector>
```

My `Activity` implements the click listener and I pass it in RecycklerViewAdapter`s constructor. 
This is the code that handle the clicks on buttons in the recyclerview in the Activity:

```
 @Override
    public void onRecyclerItemClicked(View view, int position) {
        mAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
        lastSelectedButtonPosition = position; //value for savedInstance
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mRecycler.scrollToPosition(position);

        loadFragment(position);
    }
```

Depends on the `position`, I load a fragment in the activity which shows DialogFragment in order to display loading screen, until data is fetched and so on.
But after DialogFragment is displayed the pressed button in the recyclerview is no longer pressed.
Anyone has an idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a POJO class like this.

```
public class RecyclerViewItem{
  String buttonName;
  boolean isSelected;
  public boolean getSelected(){
    return isSelected;
  }
 public void setSelected(boolean isSelected){
   this.isSelected = isSelected;
 }
public void setName(String buttonName){
   this.buttonName = buttonName;
 }
public String getName(){
   return buttonName;
 }
```

}

use this to populate items in RecyclerView. Set the isSelected attribute according to the item which you have selected. So that the item will remain selected even if the list is refreshed in between.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but did not helped.